# Whats the best approach for handling a template picker in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have been dealing with this situation for a while now. I have been programming in objective C for about four years now but only for the iphone platform. I am currently working on my first mac osx application and would like some help on the best practices for handling a template picker when the app launches. To be more specific the transition between the template picker view and the window. For example in the application pages, the application allows you to select a template in the first view that is loaded and then after you have chosen your template that view disappears completely and you then receive a new view that is specifically for editing purposes. I currently have an application that loads the first view fine allows for selection in an IKImagebrowser and loads a separate view although I don't know if this is the best approach for doing this and also I can't seem to get the view with the Imagbrowser in it to disappear after I load the second view. If someone could shed some light on this situation for me it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is not much wrong with what your doing... although BASIC difference between iphone programming and MAC programming is that in iphone programming we use the IK kit and in MAC prograamming we dont..all the classes used in MAC programming (not necessarily) but most use NS.... KEEP in mind that in MAC programming , a single button can launch a SINGLE action or call a single method unlike in iphone SDK where u can connect a button with multiple method calls.

my suggestion to u is put a working or busy sign and set its alpha value to zero, wheen first app is closed, dont close it there...instead change gamma value and load the next view...When that is loaded(KEEP THEIR POSITON(x,y) exactly same , hide the previous view app or first app...that way the transition would seem like its a single app....
hope this helps